# Transaction Return Type in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a transaction as:

```
  @commit(false)   
  @returns(Integer)   
  transaction SampleTransaction {
    o String id optional   
  }
```

Now, My transaction returns integer normally, but when I try to return 0 (which is also an Integer), the transaction function returns alphanumeric string instead of 0(Zero).

The same thing happens when I try to return false in a Boolean return type transaction.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a `console.log('Result' + yourNumber)` before you return it to review what is returning your method in your logic.js.

After you do the transaction you can check your logs making:

```
docker ps
docker logs <container id> (and look for you log)
```

These probably is a bug of the CTO language, maybe as a workaround you can catch when the value it's 'Zero' and return 0 instead.

Comment: Thanks @Diego. I've checked the logs also. All seems correct. There must be a bug.